# UIImageView is not removed from Superview in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

So , i have this void where i initialize the GUI and remove it when it's clicked the play image i call it with [self GUI:1]; and [self GUI:0];

The GUI comes up but when i try to hide it it's not working but it's entering in the if()

```
-(void)GUI:(int)action{
    // GUY LOADING
    UIImageView *menu =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x-350/2,self.view.center.y-300/2,350,200)];
    UIImageView *menuplay =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x-270/2,self.view.center.y-50/2,133,50)];
    UIImageView *menuretry =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x+5,self.view.center.y-50/2,133,50)];
    menu.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"menustart.png"];
    menuplay.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuplay.png"];
    menuretry.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"retrymenu.png"];
    if(action == 1){
        [self.view addSubview:menu];
        [self.view addSubview:menuplay];
        [self.view addSubview:menuretry];

    }

    if(action == 0){
        [menu removeFromSuperview];
        [menuplay removeFromSuperview];
        [menuretry removeFromSuperview];

    }
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(StartGame:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [menuplay setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [menuplay addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

}
```

the StartGame selector only executes the following code

```
[self GUI:0];
```

and the viewDidLoad only executes the following code

```
[self GUI:1];
```

Comment: What's a void? May be best if you learn the correct terms. And why do you have a comment that says `// GUY LOADING`? Why are you loading a guy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time the methode `GUI:` is called, no it not called a `void` you create new instance of the imageviews.  Also `GUI` is not a good name for a method, better would be something like: `setMenuVisible:`

Since there is no reference to the old, previous image view they can not removed, You need to keep a reference to the image views.

So in your header do the following:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *menu;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *menuplay;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *menuretry;
```

Then in you `GUI:` methode:

```
-(void)GUI:(int)action{
    // GUY LOADING
    if (!self.menu) {
        self.menu =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x-350/2,self.view.center.y-300/2,350,200)];
        menu.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"menustart"];
    }

    if (!self.menuplay) {
        self.menuplay =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x-270/2,self.view.center.y-50/2,133,50)];
        menuplay.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuplay"];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(StartGame:)];
        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [menuplay setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [menuplay addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    }
    if (!self.menuretry) {
        self.menuretry =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x+5,self.view.center.y-50/2,133,50)];
        menuretry.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"retrymenu"];
    }


    if(action == 1){
        [self.view addSubview:self.menu];
        [self.view addSubview:self.menuplay];
        [self.view addSubview:self.menuretry];
    }
    else if(action == 0){
        [self.menu removeFromSuperview];
        [self.menuplay removeFromSuperview];
        [self.menuretry removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```